# Is the cardinality of a set its modulus?

Tags: terminology

Cardinality and modulus share a symbol ($|a|$). Is cardinality just a special name for the modulus of a set?

Comment: No. The cardinality of $A$ denotes the class of all the sets $B$ such that there is a bijection $A\to B$. In ZFC, the cardinality of $A$ may be identified with the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that there is a bijection $A\to \alpha$.

Comment: The symbol $|x|$ just means "the size of $x$ _in some manner_".  Modulus, cardinality, determinant, measure, etc. all share the same symbol because they all somehow measure "size" (whatever that means).  You shouldn't mix them up, though, as they will often be inconsistent with each other.

Comment: How does one define the modulus of a set?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish At the intersection, we have objects like Dedekind cuts, so there are certainly _some_ sets that have a well-defined modulus in the sense of analysis/geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulus operator $|\cdot|$ on $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) acts on a different space than the "cardinality operator" $|\cdot|$, which acts on the space of sets. They are not the same operation, although they share some similarities - both give, in a certain sense, the "size" of the objects they act on. The modulus operator returns the magnitude of a complex number $\mathbb{C}$, while the cardinality of a set returns the number of elements a set contains. But the operations are certainly distinct for a multitude of reasons. Another reason is that the modulus operator is always a finite real value - for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $|z|\in\mathbb{R}$. The same cannot be said of the cardinality operator, which may take values in $\mathbb{N}$ or any of the "cardinal numbers" $\aleph_0,\aleph_1,\ldots$, and so forth. They simply do not even have the same domain and range.